# Assigning an increment value to dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic input fields generated from a jquery function. There is the ability to add or delete through button clicks these input fields. The fields are populated with data from mysql table. Each populated input has a unique ID fetched from the DB. When adding a new field I am getting the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` from an ajax request. I am then able to increment +1 but for all fields. I only want to do this for the new fields. If by some reason an insert query transaction is made from another app it will update `start increment from` field and then update the rest with the correct values (check to see what I mean jsFiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/f9XP8/2/).

The problems is how to put it all together. I just want to follow to able to add a new field and assign it the appropriate next `person_id` for db insert. [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test_values3.php)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $increment_num = $('#increment_num');
    var interval = 100;  //3000 = 3 seconds
    function doAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'personAutoIncrement.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                    var $cloned = $('#input_table tr');
                    var num = parseInt(data);
                    $increment_num.val(num);
                    $cloned.each(function(i){
                        $(this).find('[name^="increment_id"]').first().val(num+i);
                    })
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                // Schedule the next
                setTimeout(doAjax, interval);

        }
    });
    }
    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
    var click_count = 0;
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    click_count++;
        var $clones     = $('#input_table tr'),
            num         = $clones.size() + 1,
            next_num    = parseInt($clones.last().find('input[name^="increment_id"]').val()) + 1,
            $template   = $clones.first(),
            newSection  = $template.clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_'+num),
            ident       = 'increment_id_'+num;
            person_id = 'person_id_'+num;
            person_fname = 'person_fname_'+num;
            person_lname = 'person_lname_'+num;

        // clear out all sections of new input
        newSection.find('input').not('[name^="increment_id"]').val('');

        newSection.find('input[name^="increment_id"]').attr({
            'id': ident,
            'name': ident
        }).val(/*next_num*/);
        newSection.find('input[name^="person_id"]').attr({
            'id': person_id,
            'name': person_id
        }).val(/*next_num*/);
        newSection.find('input[name^="person_fname"]').attr({
            'id': person_fname,
            'name': person_fname
        }).val(/*next_num*/);


        $('#input_table').append(newSection);
        $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', '');
        if (num == 100) $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many duplicate input fields we currently have
        $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', '');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID from DB</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="input_table">
        <tr id="pq_entry_1">
            <td><input type="text" id="increment_id_1" name="increment_id_1" readonly value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add text box' />
<input type='button' id='btnDel' value='Delete' /></br>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just delegate the AUTO_INCREMENT field to your db-layer? You shouldn't mess up with it on the client: even showing the ID field is a bad idea in general. I'd prefer to retrieve new ids after the final submit, directly from the server (i.e. the db-server).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or a similar RDBMS?

Comment: @RobM. I am using MySQL. WOuld you like me to paste the mysql/php code?

Comment: @RobM. Any ideas to get this accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are wanting to know how to increment certain rows, but allow others to be "frozen" (because they are saved to the database). I have changed your code a bit more, here are the important notes:

1. I removed the dynamic name attributes. You don't need to dynamically generate field names, you can just assign data-* attributes to hold the id or refer to `tr.find('input[name="person_id"]')`
2. Added a `data-saved` attribute to the `tr` to know whether or not it should be included in the updated `auto increment id` or if it should just stay as it is
3. Added a save button next to each row, which as it is just sets the `data-saved` attribute on the row, you can add an AJAX call to save the record if you want

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9XP8/3/)

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $increment_num = $('#increment_num');
    var interval = 5000;  //3000 = 3 seconds
    function doAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'personAutoIncrement.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var $cloned = $('#input_table tr').not('[data-saved]');
                var num = parseInt(data);
                $increment_num.val(num);
                $cloned.each(function(i){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.find('[name^="person_id"]').first().val(num+i);
                })
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                // Schedule the next
                setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
    var click_count = 0;

    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        click_count++;
        var $clones     = $('#input_table tr'),
            num         = $clones.size() + 1,
            next_num    = parseInt($clones.last().find('input[name^="person_id"]').val()) + 1,
            $template   = $clones.first(),
            newSection  = $template.clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_'+num),
            person_id   = 'person_id_'+num;
            person_fname = 'person_fname_'+num;
            person_lname = 'person_lname_'+num;

        newSection.removeAttr('data-saved');

        // clear out all sections of new input
        newSection.find('input[type="text"]').val('');

        newSection.find('input[name^="person_id"]').attr({
            'id': person_id
        }).val(next_num);

        newSection.find('input[name^="person_fname"]').attr({
            'id': person_fname
        });

        newSection.find('input[type="button"]').attr('data-ident', next_num);


        $('#input_table').append(newSection);
        $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', '');
        if (num == 100) $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('.save-button').click(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parents('.clonedSection')
        var id = $parent.find('input[name="person_id"]').val();
        // do whatever else here, save to db
        $parent.attr('data-saved', '1');
    })

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many duplicate input fields we currently have
        $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', '');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form>
<strong>Start Increment from Next ID to be inserted in the DB:</strong><input id="increment_num" name="increment_num"  type="text" /></br>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>ID from DB</th><th></th>
        <th>First Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="input_table" >
        <tr id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection" data-saved="1">
            <td><input type="text" name="person_id" value='1' readonly /></td>
            <td><input id="person_fname_1" name="person_fname" placeholder=" First Name" type="text" value='James'/></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="save-button" value="Save" />
        </tr>
        <tr id="pq_entry_2" class="clonedSection" >
            <td><input type="text" name="person_id" value='2' readonly /></td>
            <td><input id="person_fname_2" name="person_fname" placeholder=" First Name" type="text" value='Cynthia'/></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="save-button" value="Save" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another Person' />
<input type='button' id='btnDel' value='Delete' /></br>
</form>
```

Having said all of that, I probably would approach this differently by having a hidden element:

`<input type="hidden" name="person_id" value="1" />`

That when a new row was generated was nullified:

`<input type="hidden" name="person_id" value="" />`

Then in my PHP, I would allow MySQL to handle auto incrementing the id in a manner like this:

```
<?php
    $params = $_POST;
    if(is_numeric($params['person_id'])){
       $sql = sprintf('UPDATE person SET fname = "%s", lname = "%s" WHERE person_id = %u LIMIT 1', 
          mysql_real_escape_string($params['fname']), 
          mysql_real_escape_string($params['lname']), 
          intval($params['person_id'])
       );
    } else {
       // the NULL tells MySQL to select the correct next increment id automatically
       $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO person (id, fname, lname) VALUES (NULL, "%s", "%s")',
         mysql_real_escape_string($params['fname']),
         mysql_real_escape_string($params['lname']);
       );
    }

?>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! thankyou. A small consultation: Since I am doing an ajax call every 3 seconds, should I consider doing [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)(SSE's)?

Comment: Glad I could help. Regarding SSE,  I would personally opt for websockets, but if you have experience with SSE and it fits your use case then sure :)

Comment: Thank you. I would read more into it. Rob what would suggest for deleting a user from DB when clicking `delete` button?

Comment: I would move the delete button into each row (like the save button) and use logic very similar to the click handler I defined for `$('.save-button')`

Comment: Rob another consultation, in regards to the `delete new field button` (this is not related to the `delete user button`): How can I have the the fields populated from values from the DB not be able to be removed? Have them somehow locked in. A user can add new fields or delete those new fields but they cant, delete the fields there already.

Comment: I made a question to make it formal [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447448/deleting-input-fields-dynamically-that-dont-have-a-unique-attribute)

Comment: Using the same if(elem.not('[data-saved'])) check

Comment: I have an new question regarding something similar, would you please be able to assist me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485967/add-values-to-select-field-dynamically

Comment: could you give me some guidance/help on this [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485967/add-values-to-select-field-dynamically)? It has more dynamic fields but the purpose is the same.